# Residual Problems from Failed Backup "File XXXXXX is Writable By Group"

Tags: php, magento, indexing

So I learned about a solution for my backup that crashed the system . . .but it looks like there are lingering issues.   This error is similar to the one I had (and fixed), but I could not find anything relate to "writeable by group".   Here is the error I got.   I am getting it when I try to go to Magento Connect so that I can add an extension.
Internal Server Error

File "/home/mydomain/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/downloader/index.php" is writeable by group

suPHP 0.7.1

Crikey, here's hoping this is the last residual effect from a failed backup.

Comment: so...change the file permissions from 664/666, to 644.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it from 666 to 644 to get my system up and running again .  . . .but this is still remaining issue.   Are you saying to change it again?

Comment: Yeah, tried changing to all three.   Only one that works is 644, but Magento Connect still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on Magento 1.9.3.1. When I try to make a backup clicking the *"System Backup"* button, the file permissions of the `index.php` and other files are automatically changed to **666**. This will cause the error:

> **500 Internal Server Error**
>
> File ".../index.php" is writeable by group

So you will need to change permissions of the `index.php` to **644**.

File permissions are not changed when I select the other types of backup (e.g. *"Database Backup"*), it happens only when I choose *"System Backup"*.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple do it set your root directory permission to 755 and var folder to 777 and clear cache from var directory.